# Interesting API pattern

Tags: java, api, design-patterns

While studying the Neo4J source code I noticed that they use a very interesting pattern for decoupling interface from implementation. There is a [Node](https://github.com/neo4j/community/blob/master/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.java) interface that is implemented only by the [NodeProxy](https://github.com/neo4j/community/blob/master/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/NodeProxy.java) class. NodeProxy in turn delegates to [NodeImpl](https://github.com/neo4j/community/blob/master/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/NodeImpl.java) which you would think that implements Node too, but it doesn´t. NodeImpl has the same methods with the same signature and is the backing implementation of Node, but it doesn't implement Node. I have used the proxy pattern before but would have made NodeImpl to implement Node as NodeProxy does. Any ideas about the advantages this pattern brings?

Edit 1: Thanks to Cirkel's comment I now know that is called [Bridge pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) and the main objective is to "decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently", interesting.

Comment: How does `NodeProxy` delegate to `NodeImpl`? `NodeProxy` does not use `NodeImpl` in any way. It's the other way around - `NodeImpl` uses `NodeProxy`.

Comment: Not sure what the benefits are because I know absolutely nothing about the framework you're looking at, but sounds like NodeProxy acts much like a service locator of a kind.

Comment: It is called _Bridge pattern_

Comment: @Cirkel Can't upvote enough, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Cirkel would yo mind to make your comment an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `NodeImpl` a bit more detailed, you see that the methods there corresponding to the `Node` methods have different signatures - they additionally take a `NodeManager` argument.

This alone makes it impossible for them to implement the Node interface.

The NodeProxy then maintains a reference to a NodeManager, which it then can pass to the NodeImpl objects.

Answer (score 1):

The net of it is that it forces you to go through NodeProxy rather than working with NodeImpl directly. I'm not familiar enough with Neo4J to say why it would advantageous to do it in that context. Perhaps NodeProxy is instrumented with additional behaviors that NodeImpl doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

The main effect of this implementation would be that the dependencies are reverted. If you let NodeImpl implement Node, then NodeImpl would depend on Node. By introducing NodeProxy you let NodePoxy depend on NodeImpl while NodeImpl does not depend on anything. This could possibly be an advantage or neccesary for some reason in a specific context.

Comment: Sure but NodeProxy depends on Node as well, so instead of having one object dependent of Node, we now have an Object dependent on NodeImpl and Node and one dependent on Node - hard to see the advantage, but probably they have to work around some strange limitations/requisites we don't know of